# How can I run a test in deployment mode with WicketTester?

Tags: wicket-tester

I want to run my tests in WicketTester in deployment mode? Is it possible to do that? I tried searching the web, but WicketTester is not really well documented.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. If you call the `WicketTester` constructor you can pass a parameter of type `WebApplication`. The `WebApplication` object defines if your application is running in development or deployment mode. If your using a DummyWebApplication and always want to run your tests in deployment mode just override `getConfigurationType()`like shown below:

```
WicketTester.DummyWebApplication application = new WicketTester.DummyWebApplication() {
        @Override
        public String getConfigurationType() {
            return Application.DEPLOYMENT;
        }
};
WicketTester wicketTester = new WicketTester(application);
```

There are multiple other ways, like defining it in your web.xml of your application used for tests or set the system wide property `wicket.configuration`. Also check [WebApplication.getConfigurationType() on Github](https://github.com/apache/wicket/blob/e7597f03f2c605badfa114011935cb79a51f2717/wicket-core/src/main/java/org/apache/wicket/protocol/http/WebApplication.java#L789)